# MongoDB Efficiency: Find + Update or Remove + Insert?

Tags: mongodb

Just curious which of the following is more efficient if I want to "reset" a (single) document to its initial state if it exists, or create a new one if it doesn't.

```
Collection.remove({ initialField: "dirtyString" });
Collection.insert({ initialField: "initialString" });
```

or

```
let _id = Collection.findOne({ initialField: "dirtyString" });
Collection.update(_id, { initialField: "initialString" });
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does your testing indicate?

Comment: Neither! Use `collection.update` with `UpdateFlags.Upsert`.

Comment: can you give an example of that?

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with doing everything on a single command?

```
Collection.update({ initialField: "dirtyString" }, { initialField: "initialString"});
```